# Copy all pages - MediaWiki

Tags: copy, mediawiki, wiki

Any ideas on how I can easily copy all the pages off a MediaWiki site and copy them to my own site?

Comment: Which wiki? Is it a Wikimedia wiki (e.g. Wikipedia)? Do you need to keep the history of the copied pages? What about legal issues: does the license of the wiki allow you to copy it? How are you going to attribute users of the original wiki (most wiki licenses require that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Back up the database
2. Back up the MediaWiki files
3. Re-create the database, user and permissions
4. Import the database backup
5. Import the MediaWiki files
6. Check the configuration file

All the information can be found here: [Manual:Moving a wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMoving_a_wiki)

Comment: The only problem is that I no longer have access to the original server.

Comment: You can also create an XML dump for a specific set of pages using the **Special:Export** page of the wiki, although attempting to dump large quantities of pages through this interface will usually time out - you can go probably 100 pages at a time?  
And then you can import the content via the **Special:Import** page of the new wiki.

Comment: Or either you could use any of the [unofficial scripts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki#Scripts) that MediaWiki provides for exporting the content.

Answer (score 1):

create a script that loops over the pages (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages ) , get the content ( http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Main%20Page&rvprop=content ) and insert it into another MW using the [mediawiki API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php).

Comment: You can combine the two queries into one query: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=allpages&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Comment: Ok I dont really know a lot of xml

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but: Wikimedia provide dumps:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download